# validating a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form and I am trying to validate with javascript that there is a checkbox checked..I am able to get it to work with this code..

```
function validate( )
{ var message = '';
valid = true;
if (
   document.trip_form.attributename.checked == false &&
   document.trip_form.attributename.checked == false &&
   document.trip_form.attributename.checked == false) 
{
 message += "Please select a trip from the list.\n";
 valid = false;
}
```

my problem is that I am using salesforce and need to have the code to track what boxes are selected..the name attributes that are given through salesforce begin with numbers tho so I can not plug it into the attributename area..I have tried creating variables for it but I do not believe I am doing this correctly..does anyone have a general direction they can point me..

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="checkbox_trips"><label for="grand-trip" class="trips-checkbox"><input id="grand-trip" name="00NA0000009xbVA" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" value="1"/>Grand Canyon</label></div>

<div class="checkbox_trips"><label for="mammoth-trip" class="trips-checkbox"><input id="mammoth-trip" type="checkbox" name="00NA0000009xbVF" class="checkbox-row" value="1"/>Mammoth Mountain</label></div>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to have the exact same check three times?

Comment: Show us the rendered html.

Comment: no it is meant just to check that one of the boxes is checked

Comment: i haven't used this kind of syntax to access element for a long time, but i'm pretty sure you should be able to it cross browser this way: `document.trip_form['00NA0000009xbVA'].checked` or if you want to use a variable `document.trip_form[attributename].checked`.